# CasperJS querySelectorAll(variable) in function returns no results

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, selectors-api

I am in the process of writing a site scraper to grab some specific content from an ajax site with no actual links, only clickable text.  I've only been using javascript for about a week now and am using CasperJS as it will cut out a lot of work.

The problem I am finding is that I'm writing multiple functions which all do the same thing, just search for different links depending on the page it's on.
So I have:

```
function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('div.AjaxLink h3');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link) {
        return link.innerText;
    });
}
```

Its run via:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var myLinks = this.evaulate(getLinks);
    /* ... link manipulation code code ... */
});
```

This works fine.  I obviously don't want to have half a dozen functions which simply have a different query string. So what I want to do is:

```
function getLinks(findText) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(findText);
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link) {
        return link.innerText;
    });
}
```

Then I am trying to run it via:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var myLinks = getLinks('div.AjaxLink h3');
    /* ... link manipulation code code ... */
});
```

The findText variable is passed in properly but it appears the query selector always returns an empty NodeList.

What am I doing wrong? Is ***document*** an empty document created inside that function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS. PhantomJS has two contexts. The sandboxed page context that is accessible through [`evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) and the outer context which has access to `require` and `phantom`. Strangely enough, both contexts have access to `window` and `document`, but `document` doesn't mean anything in the outer context, because the DOM is empty. That is why `querySelectorAll()` doesn't find an element. The page DOM can only be accessed through `evaluate()`.

So you need to execute your function in [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate). The additional argument for your function is passed into `evaluate()` and not your function:

```
function getLinks(findText) {
    ...
}

casper.then(function() {
    var myLinks = this.evaluate(getLinks, 'div.AjaxLink h3'); // THIS
    ...
});
```

There is also an important note at the bottom of the [`evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) page:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**